# WordPress add html to loginscreen with a hook

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm facing a problem here. I need to add a  to the html login/forgot password pages. I don't want to alter the defaultloginpage. Also creating a page in WP itself is no option for me since it is a WPMU with a lot of sites on it.

So my question is: Is there a way to alter these screens html (without using frontend languages). Like a hook or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, **I would advise against editing the core files** as it will be overwritten when you next update WordPress.

To create an extra field on your login page, you may use the login_form action hook:

```
add_action('login_form','my_added_login_field');
function my_added_login_field(){
    //Output your HTML
?>
    <p>
        <label for="my_extra_field">My extra field<br>
        <input type="text" tabindex="20" size="20" value="" class="input" id="my_extra_field" name="my_extra_field_name"></label>
    </p>
<?php
}
```

Next we need to verify that what they entered into the field matched what you have stored. In the following code, I've assumed you've stored the identification code as a user meta value with meta key `my_ident_code`. **You should do this rather than create your own column!**.

To verify a users you can use the authenticate filter. This passes the entered username and password. If the identification code is correct, return null to allow WordPress to verify the password and username. If it is not correct, remove the WordPress' authentication and return an error. This forces the user back to the log-in page, where they'll see the error displayed.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'my_custom_authenticate', 10, 3 );
function my_custom_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ){
    //Get POSTED value
    $my_value = $_POST['my_extra_field_name'];

    //Get user object
    $user = get_user_by('login', $username );

    //Get stored value
        $stored_value = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'my_ident_code', true);

    if(!$user || empty($my_value) || $my_value !=$stored_value){
        //User note found, or no value entered or doesn't match stored value - don't proceed.
            remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
            remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_email_password', 20); 

        //Create an error to return to user
            return new WP_Error( 'denied', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: You're unique identifier was invalid.") );
    }

    //Make sure you return null 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to edit the core. I just needed to add html without the use of frontend language. This will help me :) Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

For custom login page

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Login_Hooks

> So my question is: Is there a way to alter these screens html (without using frontend languages).

Without JS and CSS, it's difficult

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to avoid building a new screen, I just want to add one line of <noscript> code to it. I was wondering if there was a hook to do that

Answer (score 0):

Maartjie
Here's the reasonably full list of wordpress actions and filters, with link to the admin actions:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions.  login_form is the one you should be looking at.  NO js or css needed, but yes you will need php.

Comment: A good way of checking if there's a hook is to look at the source code in your local test install and seach for 'apply_filters' or 'do_action'.